# Bootcamp lost the Mac option after install BitLocker on Windows

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows

I'm using Mac 10.10 (Yosemite) with Bootcamp. On my Windows 8.1, I enabled BitLocker and restart.

Now when I press the Option button during startup, I don't see my Mac OS anymore. There is only Windows and Recovery option.

How do I recover from that ?

Comment: Bitlocker will have tried to make a new partition on the Mac's boot volume. This is not a good thing.

Comment: Sadly yes, Bitlocker messed up the Mac partition and I lost the Mac boot option. I'm trying to look for a solution using `gdisk`  sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/

Comment: I'm sorry, it's beyond my abilities - I just know it's not a safe option, Windows does not understand the way the Mac fools it into thinking it's on an MBR disk & breaks things badly if allowed to touch the partitioning.